# How do I convert a string of escape sequences to bytes?

Tags: string, go, tcp, byte, tcpserver

Creating a TCP server that needs to process some data. I have a net.Conn instance "connection"from which I will read said data. The lower part of the snippet brings about an error noting that it cannot use the 'esc' value as a byte value.

```
const(
esc = "\a\n"
 )
....
c := bufio.NewReader(connection)
data, err := c.ReadBytes(esc)
```

Clearly, some conversion is needed but when I try

```
 const(
esc = "\a\n"
 )
....
c := bufio.NewReader(connection)
data, err := c.ReadBytes(byte(esc))
```

The compiler makes note that I cannot convert esc to byte. Is it due to the fact that I declared "\a\n" as a const value on the package level? Or is there something else overall associated with how I'm framing the bytes to be read?

Comment: That "string of escape sequences" is just a string.  The escape sequences are only in the source code, they don't exist in the in-memory representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert `esc` to `byte` because you can't convert strings into single bytes. You can convert a string into a byte slice (`[]byte`).

The `bufio.Reader` only supports single byte delimiters, you should use a [`bufio.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner) with a custom split function instead for multi-byte delimiters.

Perhaps a modified version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/37531472/1205448